# How to redirect all network traffic through Tor?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tor

The Tor browser only directs it's traffic through tor. How can I do the same with all of the network traffic on Ubuntu? Are there any programs or packages to do this?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, this might generally be a bad idea, as any app can leak information about you. You might want to use a dedicated system, e,g. a "Tails" instance in a Qemu VM.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/324685/how-to-route-all-internet-traffic-through-tor-the-onion-router

Comment: Also note that Tor can only forward some types of traffic.